# Hangfire Recurring Job Queue property in multiple places?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am getting the a list of the recurring jobs in the System that I have added to a specific queue 'notes'.

```
var rjobs = storage.GetRecurringJobs();
```

This works fine and returns a list of RecurringJobDto objects. This class has a 'Queue' property which always seems to be = 'default'. It also has a 'Job' object property which has its own 'Queue' property, and that is set correctly to the 'notes' queue.

Is that normal that they are different? Or am I doing something incorrectly or forgetting to do something that would set both Queue properties?

I create the job with:

```
client.Create<IServiceInterface>(s => s.ProcessJob(), new EnqueuedState("notes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We creating the hangfire server you can define queues :

```
services.AddHangfireServer(a =>
{
    a.WorkerCount = Math.Min(Environment.ProcessorCount * hangfireConfiguration.WorkerCount, 10);
    a.Queues = new[] { "default", "lowprio" };
});
```

If you don't - hangfire will create a "default" and every job will end up in that queue.